# Calling Octave file from python and vice versa in raspberry pi

Tags: octave

I have written **gpio** settings and **camera** code in **python** and face recognition code in **octave**. what I want is first to run the python gpio code and then call the octave code and then back to python. how to do it in raspberry pi?? ***plz elaborate***

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried so far? The simples way would be to write a bash script which captures the image using your python camera code (btw, you can capture your raspberry cam directly in Octave using image-acquisition package), save the image to a file, then call Octave to process it.

Or you use a client/server approach and let python and octave communicate via sockets.

Or use oct2py: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/oct2py

There are too many possibilities to list them all.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Python subprocesses to call Octave.  There's a subprocessing module with calls like `popen`.  These can work with or without a shell.

The easiest approach is to save the relevant data to files (there's a `scipy` module with functions to save and load .mat files).  Then call the octave script, passing the input/output file names.  Octave processes, with the appropriate switches (no banner, etc), start up quickly.  Obviously this is not time efficient for trivial Octave tasks.  It also works with the Python multiprocessing module.

It is relatively easy to test this approach in pieces, since once you have the data files written, you can invoke the Octave script from the shell.

Octave also has `popen` wrappers.  In one case years ago I called Python from Octave, and used the Python multiprocessing to spawn a number of Octave processes.  Kind of a poor-man's answer to MATLAB's parellel functionality.